# problems with deleting a cell of a table

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

in my table (`UITableView`) I use cells with a `UITextField` istead of `UILabel`, added to the cell by "addSubview". I need this, because I want my cells to become directly be editable. As cell-style I use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. - Everything works fine: I can add and edit cells whenever I want.

However, deleting makes a problem: When I "delete" a cell and make a `reloadData` ot the table, the cell still displays its old content, together with the new one. Also the same for all cells below it. When I close my app and start it again, the table is displayed correctly.

Here the code I use to delete the cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
                                            forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSUInteger count = [datas count];

if (row <= count) {

    NSString* data = [datas objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    [self deleteDatas:data];
}

[self.locationTable reloadData];
```

}

Where in `deleteDatas` I just delete the corresponding datas from a file, which works correctly, as "prooved" by new loading the app.

Here

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
}

// Configure the cell.

// table cell with uitextfield instead of lable.
UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 185, 30)];
textField.enabled = NO;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

NSUInteger count = [datas count];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

// last cell is empty to edit it
if (row+1 < count) {

    textField.text = [datas objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}

return cell;
```

}

Any idea? - Thanks

Any idea, why my cell shows twice the content (once of the original cell and once the content of the cell below?) - I think s.th. is wrong with reloading the cell. - Is it possible that the textfield makes problems? - How can I figure this out?

Comment: can you post the code which you write in your method called - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: and also check your IBOutlet connections

Comment: paste your cellFroRowAtIndexPath here.

Comment: Please find code above.How can I check the IBOutlet connetion for the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should also remove the element from your mutablearray, in commitEditingStyle...

```
NSString* data = [datas objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
[self deleteDatas:data];
[datas removeObjetAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

Otherwise at your next reloadData the string is still there in memory and is displayed in cellForRow...

Comment: is already done in `deteDatas:data´. There i "create" `datas´ new

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write your commitEditingStyle: method more like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    if (indexPath.row <= [data count]) {
      // Update the model by deleting the actual data
      NSString* data = [datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      [self deleteDatas:data];
      // Delete the row from the table
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }
  }
}
```

Other things to check, are that your method for tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: returns the correct data, if it doesn't, then you'll get assertion failures when the table tries to remove rows, and the logic doesn't add up.

Comment: Code results in assertion failures, so my `numberOfRowsInSection´ is wrong?

Comment: yeah, possibly. Can you paste what deleteDatas: does? Why not just do [datas removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ?